# Using Spinnaker to deploy a Docker image from dockerhub to Aws Eb

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, spinnaker

Very new to Spinnaker/Docker. What we're trying to do is use Spinnaker to simply retrieve a Docker image that has been pushed to hub.docker.com, and deploy it to an application in AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Our spinnaker server is running on a VM in EC2. We want to use spinnaker because of it's support for load balanced deployments with approval chains,etc.

The only reference articles around this topic involve Kubernetes, which is yet another platform I'm unfamiliar with. I'm quite confused because logically, pulling a Docker image out of dockerhub and deploying it to Aws should be one of this basic forms of deployment around. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS EB is not a supported deployment platform for Spinnaker. Each platform needs to have a series of operations and caching requirements satisfied in Spinnaker's cloud provider integration service, [Clouddriver](https://github.com/spinnaker/clouddriver). This is a non-trivial amount of work and so far no one has stepped up to do it. If you (or anyone else) is interested in adding support you can reach us in the #dev channel in [Slack](http://join.spinnaker.io) and we'll be more than happy to guide you through it.

Comment: Is this now supported?